# Line integral, half circle, polar coordinate the only way

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

In solving Line Integrals, C is the upper half of x^2+y^2=1 from (1,0) to (-1, 0).

do we have to set,

```
x=cos(t), y=sin(t)
dx=-sin(t), dy=cos(t)
0<t<pi
```

or can we use the start/end points and use a line segment.

```
r(t)=(1-t)r0 + tr1
    =(1-t)<1,0> + t<-1,0>
    =<1-t, 0> + <-t1,0>
    =<1-2t, 0>
r'(t) = <-2, 0> 
0<t<1
```

Even though the line moves along the circle axis, since we have the start and end point, can't we just use the line segment method? 
instead of polar coordinates?

Comment: Given that your path of integration has a constant radius, IMO polar coordinates are probably easier since the radius is just $1$ and you will be integrating only $\theta$.

Comment: @aleden However, it does mean the rules allow me to right? I'm trying to understand the rules better cause im not able to prove it yet

Comment: When parametizing a line integral, note that $\rm dxdy=r\rm drd\theta$.

This is due to the [Determinant of the Jacobian Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) and is commonly used in multivariable calculus.

Comment: In particular see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Example_2:_polar-Cartesian_transformation).

Comment: @aleden okay. the reason why i wanted to confirm this was because I see problems with sin,cos intertwined (ex. cos(2cost + sint) etc) deeply. and such problem's seem easier to solve by not changing to polar coordinates

Comment: If the integrand is conservative (path-independent), then you can substitute another path with the same endpoints, but that's not always the case.